# how to create next and previous for not sequence auto increment column

Tags: php, mysqli

I have table contains many columns ( content_id , content_type, ..so on).
I used the code that allow me to move to the next and previous row based on the content_type and content_id.

but I want to improve the code to be able to move to the next row which its id not sequential with the other contents

Example:

in the below table I want to implement Next and Previous link that will allow to navigate all content_type of Video( 1 - 2 - 5 - 7 ) by clicking on the next and previous link

```
--------------------------------------------
content_id   content_type    content_name 
-----------------------------------------
   1            Video           A       
-----------------------------------------
   2            Video           B       
-----------------------------------------
   3            Audio           C       
-----------------------------------------
   4            Audio           D       
-----------------------------------------
   5            Video           E       
-----------------------------------------
   6            Audio           F       
-----------------------------------------
   7            Video           G       
-----------------------------------------
```

```
    $nextQuery = "SELECT * FROM contents WHERE content_type ='Video' && content_id = 1 + " .$id."  LIMIT 1 ";
    $nextResult = mysqli_query($conn,$nextQuery);
    $nextRow = mysqli_num_rows($nextResult);

    if($nextRow == 0){

        $next = "<a href='#' >Next</a>";
        print_r($nextRow);

    }else{

        $fetchNext = mysqli_fetch_array($nextResult);
        print_r($fetchNext);
        print_r($nextRow);
        $next = "<a href='../services_tools/Watch.php?content_id=". $fetchNext['content_id']."' >Next</a>";

    }

    $prevQuery = "SELECT content_id FROM contents WHERE content_type ='Video' && content_id =".$id." -1  LIMIT 1";
    $prevResult = mysqli_query($conn,$prevQuery);
    $prevRow = mysqli_num_rows($prevResult);

    if($prevRow == 0){

        $pre = "<a href='#' >Pre</a>";

    }else{

        $fetchPre = mysqli_fetch_array($prevResult);

        $pre = "<a href='../services_tools/Watch.php?content_id=".$fetchPre['content_id']."' >Pre</a>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand you correct, you just want the next (previous) `content_id` with the same `content_type`?

For this you simply need to fetch all bigger ids, order them ascending and take the first one. This is all possible in one sql statement and yours is close to this:

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE content_type ='Video' AND content_id > ".$id." ORDER BY content_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

and for previous you take all smaller one and order them descending

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE content_type ='Video' AND content_id < ".$id." ORDER BY content_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The result would contain the next/prev element or null, if its the end or the first one.

As a side note, better use prepared statements!

Answer (score 1):

For finding next results, how about you try getting all of the queries **after** the ID, and then limiting by one:

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE content_type='Video' && content_id > $id ORDER BY content_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

For finding previous results, you can do a similar thing, except with a lesser than sign (`<`). This will get all results that come before the id, but they will be in the wrong order. For example, if you're id was `4`, you would get `1`, as it would be in the order `123` (if we had no `LIMIT`). Thus, we need to reverse the results, which we can do by adding `ORDER BY content_id DESC` before the `LIMIT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE content_type='Video' && content_id < $id ORDER BY content_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This works as even if the results are not sequential, the ones that come first are always smaller than the ones that come afterward.

---

Also, just as a note, if you're not sanitizing `$id` beforehand, you'll be at risk of [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or at least [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: In the first case you also have to add `ORDER BY content_id ASC`, as any order could be returned by the database.

Comment: @FabianN. Added. I guess I just forgot to put this in as OP did not have it in their original code. Thanks